# JWT with no expires date

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, identitymodel

I'm using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` to create a `JWT` but I need a token with no expiration date, can I create that token with the `CreateJwtSecurityToken` function? I tried ignoring the `expires` parameter but that not work.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to have the ASP.NET WEB.API to ignore the expire dates of the token using this property:

[TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.validatelifetime?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-tokenvalidationparameters-validatelifetime)

You set it inside AddJwtBearer(...);

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)